# How can I customize p:polarAreaChart tooltips?

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

I have a polar area chart

```html
<p:polarAreaChart
    rendered="#{someBean.modelToDisplay != null}"
    model="#{someBean.createPolarAreaModel(someBean.modelToDisplay, true)}"
    style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
/>
```

which I want to customize the tooltips of. When I add a label and a value

```java
values.add(10);
labels.add("height");
```

the tooltip I see on the chart is always

```
height: 10
```

and I want it to be

```
height: someOtherValue
```

or at least only "height". But I could not find a way to configure them.
I can hide them using

```java
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setEnabled(false);
polarAreaChartOptions.setTooltip(tooltip);
```

but that's all I could do.

Comment: Check if you can with plain charts.js and then either use plain css or the PrimeFaces extender feature

Comment: @Kukeltje I was about to reference https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/charts?id=extender ;-)

Comment: So, there is no way I can handle this with pure Java?

Comment: Sure, you can generate the script in java and 'inline' it  in the xhtml via EL

Comment: Please either create an answer or remove the question (or find a duplicate in SO and mark it as such)

Comment: Then I will be waiting for a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a script section to my xhtml with the following JS code:

```js
<h:outputScript>
    function configurePolarChart() {
        let options = $.extend(true, {}, this.cfg.config).options
        options.tooltips = {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem) {
                    switch (tooltipItem.index) {
                        case 0:
                            return "Lower-Temperature"
                        case 1:
                            return "Upper-Temperature"
                        case 2:
                            return "Height"
                        case 3:
                            return "Weight"
                        case 4:
                            return "Length"
                        case 5:
                            return "Age"
                        default:
                            return "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.cfg.config.options = options
    }
</h:outputScript>
```

corresponding to the 6 values in my data. I also added

```java
polarAreaModel.setExtender("configurePolarChart");
```

to my .java file while creating polar area chart. Now it displays custom tooltips for each item in the chart.